# execute GTK app from SSH terminal

Tags: raspbian, python

I installed `bluetooth-sendto` in raspberry.

but when i want use this app via `bluetooth-sendto --device=6C:0E:0D:3A:1F:90 ~/WORK/TEST.mp3` give me error :

```
** (bluetooth-sendto:28746): WARNING **: Could not open X display
Unable to init server
Cannot open display:
```

how i use this app via terminal and ssh or via python script ?
i don't want display and see progress

is a way to run fake X server or something else ?

Edit : i installed `xvfb` and tried `xvfb-run -a bluetooth-sendto --device=6C:0E:0D:3A:1F:90 ~/WORK/TEST.mp3`

and this time ERROR :

```
** (bluetooth-sendto:17090): WARNING **: Error retrieving accessibility bus addr                                                                           ess: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not pr                                                                           ovided by any .service files
```

Comment: Do you have "boot to desktop" enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Xwindows forward through ssh you need to add -X flag, so the command should be:

> ssh -X IP address